# How often Niantic update map in Pokemon GO?

Tags: pokemon-go

I'm trying to improve my chances in getting Ex-raid pass in Pokemon GO. 
What I've figured out from research is that Ex-raid passes are given to (some) players that had raided Gyms in parks. Since cites can create new parks (which happened in my hometown) and that new park could contain existing gym would Niantic update that information?

How often Niantic update information from Open Street Map to Pokemon Go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't have a set frequency for updating is the short answer.

**According to a AMA that Niantic did the following question was asked:**

Q89: mogu squad - I have edited OpenStreetMap because the roads were disappeared on the scanner by switching from Google map to OSM. When will the editing result be reflected in Ingress?

A89: We are still determining the update frequency.

**The Source:**

https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/7jks3z/confirmation_that_osm_is_permanent_and_may/